# I wanna use counterup.js in my WordPress site but it shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html
js. In normal html it work fine but when i used this script in WordPress it shows Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error.
My script is

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/jquery.counterup.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 1000
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

And my html is

```
<div> <span class="counter" style="display: inline-block; width: 32%">100</span> <span class="counter" style="display: inline-block; width: 32%">58</span> <span class="counter" style="display: inline-block; width: 32%">85</span> </div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> ` and try again. Let me know the output.
Also apply `TommyBs` answer.

Comment: Can I have look in to your site ?

Comment: Sorry i am working offline right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this .You are not including script correctly.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/jquery.counterup.js">
```

You need to en-queue scripts properly using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

```
wp_enqueue_script('mycounter',bloginfo('template_directory').'/includes/jquery.counterup.js',array('jquery'));
```

Also load jquery before other scripts if there are any dependencies.

WordPress comes with bundled **jQuery**,it's recommended to use that instead using external ones.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but this is also not working.

Comment: can you check console for any script loading errors ?

Comment: I got only 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
error

Comment: which one are you using "src" or "href" for script tag ? it should be `src`

Comment: I am using href. Thank you now its working prefect when i change it to src.

Comment: Great! i strongly recommend enqueuing scripts instead of hard coding

Answer (score 1):

You're including the js file for counterup as a CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/jquery.counterup.js">
```

replace the link tag with a script tag and see if that gives any success. Also try including the jQuery library before any other plugin script, as they will most likely require jQuery

Comment: I replaced but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

Move `waypoins.min.js` link AFTER `jquery.min.js` link.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

Also `<link>` is for CSS, but you include JS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/jquery.counterup.js">
```